# escoger caracteres dentro de un string en PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera escoger unos caracteres dentro de una `URL` en `PHP` a partir de un carácter determinado.

Me explico con un ejemplo

```
http://miweb.com/rotator/?rot=65309
```

Y concretamente quisiera recoger lo que viene después del igual `=` o sea el numero del final. Este numero puede variar de numero de dígitos, por lo que la función `substr` no me vale.

```
substr($url, -5);
```

Gracias

Comment: Lo de la url, es una variable?

Comment: si lo guardo en un string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php) junto con [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://miweb.com/rotator/?rot=65309';
$query = parse_url($url)['query'];
parse_str($query, $params);
echo $params['rot'];

//Result 65309
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2db23ea4587e4f1f32c77b72ab88c5b735003fb)</kbd>